# How to trigger a function mapped to an dask array using map_blocks and store the results to an xarray or dask array without use numpy array?

Tags: python, multithreading, dask

I have 2 matrices (`data` and `result`), `result` is 2D `dask.array` and `data` is 3D `xarray.DataArray`, I must do a calc like this:

```
var_idx = 0 # const value
result[i,j] = external_function(data[var_idx,:,i],data[var_idx,:,j])
```

I am new to python and dask but after weeks of study, the code below represents what I could get to do this calc...

```
def func_block(block,block_info=None):

    @jit(nogil=True)     
    def func_external(a,b):
        # just an example
        return np.max(np.multiply(a, b))


    # result element location of data array
    # to compute just lower triangular elements     
    block_info = block_info[0]
    [(s_row,end_row),(s_col,end_col)]= block_info['array-location']
    if s_col > s_row:
        return block

    it = np.nditer(block, flags=['multi_index'],op_flags=['readwrite'])
    while not it.finished:
        (r_idx,c_idx) = it.multi_index
        row = r_idx+s_row
        col = c_idx+s_col
        if  row > col:
            it[0] = float(func_external(da_stacked_notnull[0,:,row],da_stacked_notnull[0,:,col]))
        it.iternext()

    return block

darr_zeros = da.zeros((grid_size,grid_size), chunks=(3000,3000))
darr_zeros = darr_zeros -1
dask_result = darr_zeros.map_blocks(func_block,chunks=(3000,3000),dtype=np.float16)
dask_result = xr.DataArray(dask_result.compute())
```

However, I have some issues:

1 ) If I use all data that I need I get a Python Memory Error. I imagine that its due to `dask_result.compute()`, if I understand correctly `.compute()` returns a numpy array, but I dont have enough memory to store all result in numpy array.. How can I accomplish this using dask array?

2 ) All threads uses up to 50% of each core..., and I think it is due to GIL, but dask do not improve it? Is it possible to refactor this to have a better performance?

This is the data matrix without all gridpoints that I really need :

```
da_stacked_notnull
Out[1]: 
<xarray.DataArray (variable: 1, time: 365, gridcell: 7230)>
array([[[-0.376704, -0.036332, ..., 27.715254, 26.863554],
        [-0.465122, -0.152866, ..., 27.227764, 26.556808],
        ...,
        [-0.724707, -0.520708, ..., 29.315022, 29.10007 ],
        [-0.835325, -0.704899, ..., 29.425072, 29.086765]]], dtype=float32)
Coordinates:
  * time      (time) datetime64[ns] 2015-01-01 2015-01-02 ... 2015-12-31
  * gridcell  (gridcell) MultiIndex
  - lon       (gridcell) float64 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
  - lat       (gridcell) float64 -59.5 -58.5 -57.5 -56.5 ... -32.5 -31.5 -30.5
  * variable  (variable) <U3 'sst'
```

Thanks in advance!